# How to use Stanford parser to find the parent and child of the word?

Tags: stanford-nlp

Am I right(whether or not the extraction of *parent and child* in a sentence is correct.)?

```
String sentence = "Kumi is the girl who likes dogs.";
Tree parse = lp.parse(sentence);
SemanticGraph graph = SemanticGraphFactory.makeFromTree(parse);
IndexedWord wordConnective = graph.getNodeByIndexSafe(i);//i is the index of the word
List<IndexedWord> parentWords = graph.getParentList(wordConnective);
List<IndexedWord> childWord = graph.getChildList(wordConnective);
```

If I want to extract the heads of the *who* in this sentence, how should I do?

Comment: Why are you asking us if your code is correct? Does it work properly or not?

Comment: @KenWhite I want to know whether parent and child of the code extraction in sentence is correct in English grammar.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution, using the [simple API](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/simple.html), might be:

```
new Sentence("Kumi is the girl who likes dogs").governor(4);
```

Comment: Thanks, could you give me the full code? and I want to use Stanford parser, your advice is Stanford CoreNLP, maybe they are different in some way.

Comment: I would advise just using the full Stanford CoreNLP toolkit...you can get the it here: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/